# Properly formatting a string given a python dictionary with keys that are tuples

Tags: python

I have this python dictionary.

The # of rows is 3

The # of columns is 3

```
matrix = {(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (1, 0): 4, (1, 2): 6, (2, 0): 7, (2, 1): 8}
```

The key is a tuple (row #, column #) representing the position in the matrix.

The value is the integer.

Formatted 3x3 matrix:

```
(0, 2, 3)
(4, 0, 6)
(7, 8, 0)
```

---

**How do I print out the row if I pass in 0 as the parameter for row number?***

So for the above dictionary, if I pass in 0 as a parameter for row number, it would print:

```
(0, 2, 3)
```

---

My Code so far:

```
row = 3
columns = 3

def row(row_number):
   matrix = {(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (1, 0): 4, (1, 2): 6, (2, 0): 7, (2, 1): 8}

   values = []
   for key, value in matrix.items():
      values.append(value)
```

I was thinking I could just make a list of all the keys, however, the dictionary only displays non-zero values so I am not sure what to do.

```
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Is the size of the matrix known beforehand? otherwise, it would be difficult to form boundaries of the matrix

Comment: Yes I forgot to include that information, the row and column size is 3 and already given beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script that you might find useful. I've generated a complete matrix from the available dict i.e filled 0's where the information was not present. Then indexed it accordingly.

```
#Generate empty matrix from matrix size ex: 3x3
empty_matrix = [(k, v) for k in range(0,3) for v in range(0,3)] 

print("EMPTY MATRIX:", empty_matrix)

matrix = {(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (1, 0): 4, (1, 2): 6, (2, 0): 7, (2, 1): 8}

final_list = []

#Generate complete matrix i.e fill 0's where info is not available
for element in empty_matrix:
    if element in matrix.keys():
        value = matrix.get(element)
        final_list.append([element, value])
    else:
        final_list.append([element, 0])

final_matrix = dict(final_list)
print("FINAL MATRIX:" ,final_matrix)


# Indexing the matrix
index = 0 # Get from user, 0 will retrieve 0th row and so on
print("You've retrieved row " + str(index))
for k, v in final_matrix.items():
    if index == k[0]:
        print(str(v)+',', end='')
```

Outputs:

```
EMPTY MATRIX: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
FINAL MATRIX: {(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (1, 0): 4, (1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 6, (2, 0): 7, (2, 1): 8, (2, 2): 0}
You've retrieved row 0
0,2,3,
```